# can't loop over components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render something 10 times but it gives some sort of error which is way to usual to explain here. I'm new to react and the problem  seems basic so please answer if you can. thanks

```
loop = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i<10;i++) {
        return <UI title = "Default Title" discription = "the discription for this website is null init!" />;
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.loop}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: you are not calling the function you need to write `{this.loop()}`

Comment: It's hard to be certain without seeing the exact error message but I'd be willing to bet that @AmrLabib has identified the root cause of the issue. Post your error message if you want us to be sure.

Comment: you're not calling the method , also the loop will loop only once because you return too early

Comment: Do you not see a problem with having a `return` statement in a `for`loop?

Comment: @AmrLabib, I have heard that we don't have to call function in react that way

Comment: @syed probably you are talking about event handler functions, this is different

Comment: thanks everyone really appreciate your help, it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loop() {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i<10;i++) {
        result.push(<UI title = "Default Title" discription = "the discription for this website is null init!" />);
    }
    return result;
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.loop()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy to try out...add elements to array ('squares' in this code) and then render that array.  In this case it was 50 squares, but same idea.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    var squares = [];
    for(let i = 0; i< 50; i++){
      squares.push(<div className='square'>{i}</div>);
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          I am coding!!
        </p>
        {squares}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```